# how to replace a string in a variable in GNU make?

Tags: variables, gnu-make

I have a = abc def 12345
replace 12345 with foo
I can do b = $(subst 12345, foo, $(a))
so b = abc def foo
but how could I make a = abc def foo ?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign variables with the `=` sign the right-hand side is not evaluated at the time the variable is read. Such variables are only evaluated when they are used in a rule.

When you put `b = $(subst 12345, foo, $(a))` the string "$(subst 12345, foo, $(a))" is actually saved in the b variable. You can see the problem with doing `a = $(subst 12345, foo, $(a))` - the old value of $(a) is completely lost, and the a variable now has a circular expansion.

There are a few cases where you can indeed reassign the variable using an existing definition: for example, using `+=` to append to its value. However, when this doesn't work, try using `:=` instead to assign your variables. This will evaluate the right-hand side at the time of reading the assignment. Then a later assignment using the older value will overwrite the value with the new value that has been calculated.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROJECT_NAME = $(notdir $(subst .,_,$(PWD)))
export PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**